# How to show size Ram and CPU ussage in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, ram, monitor, cpu, task-management

I am newbie in use Ubuntu so I don't know how to show Ram and CPU usage which is the same in Task Manager on Windows. It can  show by command line in Ubuntu or Application to see more.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options or even more for doing so, the one delivered with ubuntu itself is the command `top`, and you can as well have it more comfortable with `htop` which you need to install through `sudo apt-get install htop`.

Answer (score 1):

The System Monitor app should do it for you (`gnome-system-monitor`).

[image]

Comment: I will try it  and comment for you . Thank you so much